# Update all rows in a table with incrementing text value

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

How to update a column for every row in a table with an incrementing text value using SQL.

I have a table with a column called called ej_number which is a unique identifier. The field format is EJnnnn, ie EJ followed by four digits. I have imported data that doesn't include a value for ej_number, but some new rows do have it set. I want to update every row without ej_number set, starting from EJ0001. I'll resolve duplication later.

I fist did it in a loop in PHP, but realised that the server would time out because of the number of rows, so I decided to do it in SQL.

My first idea was to use a loop, but my research found that row by row updates are not recommended, especially as the only way I could see to do it would use a cursor, which is also not recommended.

I was able to do it in a single statement - the code below works, but it generates a warning (using MySQL Workbench).

```
SET @next_number = 0;
UPDATE ej_details
    SET ej_number = CASE
        WHEN ej_number IS NULL THEN (
            CONCAT('EJ', LPAD((@next_number:=@next_number+1), 4, '0')))
        ELSE ej_number
    END;
```

The statement does what I want, but generates this warning:

> 692 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please set variables in separate statements instead. Rows matched: 692  Changed: 692  Warnings: 1

I would like to know how best to do this without using a deprecated feature. I looked and found plenty of row by row solutions, but couldn't see an alternative that wasn't row by row, probably because I don't know enough to ask the right question.

Comment: How are you executing this SQL code from PHP ? It possibly needs to be 2 separate queries (`SET`, then `UPDATE`)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. This isn't the code I executed in PHP, that used PDO (prepared statements) and was a row by  row loop, and very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
SET @next_number = 0;

UPDATE ej_details
    SET ej_number = CONCAT('EJ',
                           LPAD( (@next_number:=@next_number+1), 4, '0'
                               )
                          )
    WHERE ej_number IS NULL;
```

This is simpler, but won't change the error.

If you want to do this in a single call, then:

```
UPDATE ej_details CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @next_number := 0) params
    SET ej_number = CONCAT('EJ',
                           LPAD( (@next_number:=@next_number+1), 4, '0'
                               )
                          )
    WHERE ej_number IS NULL;
```

Unfortunately, if the column is declared as `unique`, then you cannot resolve duplicate values "later".

If you wanted to solve this without the error, you'll need a primary key/unique column:

```
UPDATE ej_details ed JOIN
       (SELECT ed.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ej_number) as seqnum
        FROM ej_details ed2
        WHERE ej_number IS NULL
       ) ed2
       ON ed2.? = ed.?  -- the primary key goes here
    SET ed.ej_number = CONCAT('EJ', LPAD(ed2.seqnum, 4, '0')
                             );
```

However, this version is not backwards compatible.

I would be surprised if they really removed variables from MySQL 9.  It would break lots and lots and lots of code.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I need to master joins. ej_number is meant to be unique, but it isn't declared as such yet.There is a unique id column that can be used for the last example. I'm not worried about backwards compatibility.